# update old values in production database to new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attr-encrypted

I'm adding encryption using the `attr_encrypted` gem. Essentially all I have to do is add the gem, and rename my columns to have a prefix of `encrypted_column` before adding the line:

```
  attr_encrypted :reply, key: ENV["ANSWER_CRYPT_KEY"]
```

to my model. Now this works all and well, however I'm getting ready to push this to production, and will have some issues, because the values there are not encrypted - is there a command I can run in my rails c to loop over them and encrypt them?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise going through an intermediate step, by renaming the `reply` column to `old_reply`. You can run a migration to do that:

```
def up
  rename_column :your_table, :reply, :old_reply

  Model.reset_column_information
  Model.find_each do |instance|
    model.reply = model.old_reply #this will set the encrypted_reply based on attr_encrypted
    model.save!
  end
end
```

Once you are sure that all the encrypted values are set, you can run another migration to remove `old_reply`

Answer (score 0):

You also don't need to rename columns in the database; instead you can use `:attribute` option of the `attr_encrypted` gem.
For reference you can have a look at its documentation  [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/attr_encrypted/#The__attribute_option).